# excel formula to convert range of Number to alphabet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

excel formula to convert the range of Numbers to the alphabet

```
100 to 1.3 is A,
1.299 to 1.105 is B,
1.104 to 0.972 is C,
0.971 to 0.875 is D,
less than 0.875 is -D
```

I used the formula **=VLOOKUP(A1,{-100,"D";0.87516,"C";0.9724,"B";1.105,"A"},2,TRUE)**, but getting wrong answers like below,

```
1.3     A
1.105   A
0.9724  B
0.87516 C
```

suggest a change in my formula...

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
=MID("EDCBA",MATCH(A1,{0,0.875,0.972,1.105,1.3}),1)
```

Or, if in fact you wanted to use `-D` then use:

```
=LOOKUP(A1,{0,0.875,0.972,1.105,1.3},{"-D","D","C","B","A"})
```

[image]